# JavaFX - stage.show(); ending in program freezing

Tags: java, javafx-8

I'm trying to write a class to open an external program, make a stage that says "Please wait" with a progress indicator, wait for it to finish, then exit the stage.  If I use `primaryStage.showAndWait();` the program works, but if I use `primaryStage.show();` the program freezes and won't continue until the class is closed.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
package application;

import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;


public class Wait {
public static void display(String prog, String progPath){
    Stage primaryStage=new Stage();



    primaryStage.setTitle("Please Wait");
    primaryStage.setMinWidth(350);

    ProgressIndicator indicator = new ProgressIndicator();

    Label label1=new Label();
    label1.setText("Please wait for "+prog+" to finish...");


    HBox layout=new HBox(20);
    layout.getChildren().addAll(indicator, label1);
    layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    layout.setPadding(new Insets(20,20,20,20));

    Scene scene =new Scene(layout);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    primaryStage.show();// WHY U NO WORK?!?!?!?!

    try {

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(progPath);
        p.waitFor();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    primaryStage.close();

}
}
```

Comment: Is `Wait` the main class for your JavaFX application?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha no, it's AM.  Wait is simply a class I want to call to create a scene multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `Wait.display()` is being executed on the FX Application Thread (which is required, since it creates and displays a `Stage`), your code blocks the FX Application Thread by invoking `p.waitFor()`. Since the FX Application Thread is blocked, it can't do any of its regular work, such as rendering the UI or responding to user input.

You need to manage the process in a background thread. Using a [`Task`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) will make it easy to execute code on the FX Application Thread once the background process has finished:

```
public static void display(String prog, String progPath){
    Stage primaryStage=new Stage();

    primaryStage.setTitle("Please Wait");
    primaryStage.setMinWidth(350);

    ProgressIndicator indicator = new ProgressIndicator();

    Label label1=new Label();
    label1.setText("Please wait for "+prog+" to finish...");

    HBox layout=new HBox(20);
    layout.getChildren().addAll(indicator, label1);
    layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    layout.setPadding(new Insets(20,20,20,20));

    Scene scene =new Scene(layout);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {

            try {
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(progPath);
                p.waitFor();        
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
    };

    task.setOnSucceeded(e -> primaryStage.close());

    Thread thread = new Thread(task);
    thread.setDaemon(true); // thread will not prevent application from exiting
    thread.start();
}
```

Comment: That worked great.  Thanks!  Just note that you do need a `return null;` after the catch statements otherwise it errors out.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that... fixed it.